# Help with JOCL on Mac

Tags: java, macos, gpgpu, jocl

I am trying to run [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/opencl-part1.aspx) on my mac.

The tutorial is for windows, and packs jocl version 1.3 (JOCL-0.1.3a-beta.jar) and the native jocl dll for windows (JOCL-windows-x86_64.dll).

After getting the code, I basically got rid of the jocl 1.3 jar and the dll and substituted it with the [latest jocl 1.4 jar](http://www.jocl.org/downloads/downloads.html), that should pack resources for both mac and windows.

Afer doing this, when I run the tutorial I get the following error:

```
Error while loading native library "JOCL-apple-x86_64" with base name "JOCL"
Operating system name: Mac OS X
Architecture         : x86_64
Architecture bit size: 64
Stack trace from the attempt to load the library as a resource:
java.lang.NullPointerException: No resource found with name '/lib/libJOCL-apple-x86_64.dynlib'
```

Looks like the **libJOCL-apple-x86_64.dynlib** dynamic library is missing from the resources of the jar.

I am not a Java expert and I have no idea what to try next.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know much about jocl.org (i am the author of http://jocl.jogamp.org) but it looks like all you should need is in the lib folder. It could be a bug of jocl.org to try to load libJOCL-apple-x86_64.dynlib instead of libJOCL-apple-x86_64.jnilib on your mac. But thats only a wild guess.

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot for your feedback, in the meanwhile I also tried on windows but no luck either (I get a similar error but relative to the windows native library). I thought jocl.org was just a mirror for jocl.jogamp.org and the library was the same. I'd rather use your version, is there a way to download just the binaries somewhere on jocl.jogamp.org (cant seem to find them)? Got the source and tried to build it after converting to eclipse but its not exactly straightforward ... :)

Comment: hehe. Sure, we have binaries for all common platforms. http://jogamp.org/deployment/webstart-next/archive/ (and please take a look at our forums/mailinglists i am not that often here :) )

Answer (score 1):

use jar to extract the archive & rename /lib/libJOCL-apple-x86_64.jnilib to /lib/libJOCL-apple-x86_64.dynlib .
then re-package using jar again.